# Upgrade midi drivers?

Tags: drivers, midi

For some reason, Ubuntu is not reading midi very well consistently.

Sometimes my drumpad works perfectly.  Sometimes *exactly* every other note is ignored.  Other times it ignores at random.

I've turned my computer on/off without turning off my drum pad and it went from not working to working perfect.  Over the course of my music session, it randomly stopped working eventually.

The drum pad has no issues anywhere else, so I'm almost positive it's a midi driver issue.

Further, I've used midi-debugger software to check it wasn't just my DAW.

---

Can I upgrade my midi drivers?  Or is there some way I can verify the issue is with Ubuntu beyond what I've tried?

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details, but drivers are technically *kernel modules* thus are rather tied to your OS/release and chosen kernel stack. Ubuntu has two kernel stack choices for LTS releases, but we currently don't know what OS & release you're using (thus what choices you have available...)

Comment: If it's connected by USB, please run `lsusb`, edit your question and post the output so we can see which specific device you have. Also, please list the make and model in your question. Additionally, when you edit your question, highlight the code output and then press CTRL+K to automatically format it as code in your question. Thanks

Comment: There are no newer MIDI drivers. Please specify the model of the drumpad, and of the USB/MIDI adapter.